# keras model predict without fit, what does it mean?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I see the following example code on [tensorflow 2.0 API](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding)

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(1000, 64, input_length=10))
# the model will take as input an integer matrix of size (batch,
# input_length).
# the largest integer (i.e. word index) in the input should be no larger
# than 999 (vocabulary size).
# now model.output_shape == (None, 10, 64), where None is the batch
# dimension.

input_array = np.random.randint(1000, size=(32, 10))

model.compile('rmsprop', 'mse')
output_array = model.predict(input_array)
assert output_array.shape == (32, 10, 64)
```

I have used keras API for a few days, compile, fit and then predict is my way.

What does above example mean without fit step?

Comment: It represents the use of initialized parameters in the model without `fit()`. This example is just to illustrate the return shape of `Embedding layer`.

Comment: @giser_yugang you are right, could you put it in answer, I will close this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It represents the use of initialized parameters in the model without `fit()`. This example is just to illustrate the return shape of `Embedding layer`.